# Creating device context in OpenCL for embedded profile

Tags: c++, opencl, fpga

I am able to create context and devices in OpenCL by doing

```
     using namespace cl;
     std::vector<Platform> platforms;
     Platform::get(&platforms);
     cl_context_properties properties[] = 
                        {CL_PLATFORM_NAME,
                      (cl_context_properties) (platforms.at(0))(),0};
            context = Context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, properties);
            devices = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();
```

It is working well with CPU and GPU devices. If I try the same for FPGA devices I get error in method `clCreateContextFromType()`. The context constructor is wrapping this method.

How should I create context and devices for OpenCL devices such as  FPGA with embedded profile.

Comment: I suspect you are not linking with vendor specific OpenCL driver libraries. Hard to say more, your question is too broad. This will normally be specified in vendor documentation. For example for Altera that is [1.7.6 Managing Host Application](https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/opencl-sdk/aocl_programming_guide.pdf)

Comment: @doqtor Can you convert it to a answer? It is true for Xylinx I found examples with extensions https://github.com/Xilinx/SDAccel_Examples.

Comment: have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FPGA devices usually require to link additional vendor specific OpenCL driver libraries. What are the libraries to link with is usually specified in the vendor documentation and/or examples.

For Altera that can be found in their documentation: [1.7.6 Managing Host Application](https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/opencl-sdk/aocl_programming_guide.pdf)

For Xilinx in their examples (by OP): [github.com/Xilinx/SDAccel_Examples](https://github.com/Xilinx/SDAccel_Examples)

Comment: What is the need for vendor specific extensions for FPGA devices?

Comment: Extensions are normally used for features required by vendor that are not part of OpenCL specification or cannot be because their device is too different from what was thought for typical OpenCL device.